# Missing end cap

Tags: hub, front, through-axle

I bought a used bike, and I didn't notice the end caps were missing from the front wheel.
I don't know the model or the manufacturer of the hub, there are no markings.

It is a 12x100 thru axle fork

Hub width is 80mm (as far as I can measure)

I am unsure if I need the same end cap for both sides or if I need 2 different end caps. And I have no clue where to find the end caps.

I hope someone can help me, thanks.
[image: I put in the measurements, I hope they kind of make sense]

Comment: It's a mixed bag whether they'll be different side to side - they might be, but aren't necessarily on 12x100 hubs. The picture shown is not very useful because what's needed here is to figure out what hub it is, which generally requires identifying it by the specific shape of the hub shell and all its details. It can also be useful to know the make/model of the bike. The good news is that it might be possible to ID the hub; there's a handful of very common OEM ones and the probability is decent yours is among them. There is no generic answer short of IDing it.

Comment: Go back to the seller and ask if they still have the end caps.

Comment: Does the front hub match the rear hub?  It may be possible to test-fit the caps from the rear to the front to know exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: The bike is a Big Box store brand here in Denmark called SCO, from a sub brand called Rebel. It is about as generic as they come. Although it is fitted with GRX400 just about everywhere. Even the calipers are GRX. Shimano rotors. But the hub doesn't look like any Shimano hub I can find.

I have contacted the manufacturer, but they aren't responding. 

Closest I have come to finding something that looks like it are some genric chinese hubs like ARC, KOOZER or Shikra. With ARC being the closest.

I just checked, the end caps from the rear are not the same, they are screw on.

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005081629504.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.5.4281W4qHW4qHr8&algo_pvid=b30e9a95-fdcd-48b1-968c-113e8a6c121a&algo_exp_id=b30e9a95-fdcd-48b1-968c-113e8a6c121a-2&pdp_npi=3%40dis%21DKK%2134.72%2126.04%21%21%21%21%21%402122443916852659181584823d0790%2112000031571265953%21sea%21DK%21748511762&curPageLogUid=MIlAQ7vURRIs

On that link there are some boost adaptors that are almost spot on, but they are for 15mm. (btw, my wheel is not boost, 100mm fork)

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000969456581.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.37.4281W4qHW4qHr8&algo_pvid=b30e9a95-fdcd-48b1-968c-113e8a6c121a&algo_exp_id=b30e9a95-fdcd-48b1-968c-113e8a6c121a-18&pdp_npi=3%40dis%21DKK%21356.62%21181.88%21%21%21%21%21%402122443916852659181584823d0790%2110000012965514209%21sea%21DK%21748511762&curPageLogUid=jnmxBGDCDrJt
It looks an awful lot like this hub, but... I digress, I can't find a 12mm end cap for that either.